# C++ 11 to C# code Conversion issue

Tags: c#, c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to convert the following C++11 code to C# using Visual Studio 2012:

```
typedef enum { _A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F,_G,_H,_I,_J,_K,_L,_M,_N,_O,_1,_2,_3 }  TKeyIdentity;
typedef std::vector<TKeyIdentity const>     TKeyPath;
typedef std::vector<TKeyPath const>         TKeyMap;

const TKeyMap keyPad =
{
    { _H, _L },         // A
    { _I, _K, _M },     // B
    { _F, _J, _L, _N }, // C
    { _G, _M, _O },     // D
     { _H, _N }         // E  
}

const TKeyPath keyPadRoot =
{
    _A, _B, _C, _D, _E, _F, _G, _H, _I, _J, _K, _L, _M, _N, _O, _1, _2, _3
};

TraverseKeyPaths( TKeyPath const &keyPath, int pressesRemaining, int vowelsAllowed )
{
    for ( auto pressedKey: keyPath )
    {
          int value = TraverseKeyPaths(keyPad[ pressedKey ],pressesRemaining, vowelsAllowed - isVowel[pressedKey] );    
    }
}
```

The complete C++ code is available :http://lucid-motif.blogspot.com/2013/11/coding-puzzle-knight-sequences.html

C# Code:

```
enum TKeyIdentity { _A, _B, _C, _D, _E, _F, _G, _H, _I, _J, _K, _L, _M, _N, _O, _1, _2, _3 };
List<string> keyPadRoot = new List<string> { "_A", "_B", "_C", "_D", "_E", "_F", "_G", "_H", "_I", "_J", "_K", "_L", "_M", "_N", "_O", "_1", "_2", "_3" };

string[] A = new string[] { "_H", "_L" }; //A
string[] B = new string[] { "_I", "_K", "_M" }; //B
string[] C = new string[] { "_F", "_J", "_L", "_N" }; //C
string[] D = new string[] { "_G", "_M", "_O" }; //D

List<string> keyPadMoves = new List<string>();
keyPadMoves.AddRange(A);
keyPadMoves.AddRange(B);
keyPadMoves.AddRange(C);
keyPadMoves.AddRange(D);
.
.

int TraverseKeyPaths(List<string> keyPadRoot, int pressesRemaining, int vowelsAllowed)
{
   foreach (TKeyIdentity pressedKey in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TKeyIdentity)))
   {
      int value = TraverseKeyPaths(keyPadRoot, pressesRemaining, vowelsAllowed);
   }
 }
```

The C# code is not working as expected. The issue is with the below line:

```
 TraverseKeyPaths(keyPadRoot, pressesRemaining, vowelsAllowed);
```

I need to pass first parameter as `keyPadMoves`; but if I pass `keyPadMoves`, the recursive call goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: where is the identifier `vowels` coming from? It is also different from your C++ code which passes in the following expression: `vowelsAllowed - isVowel[pressedKey]`

Comment: It doesn't look like you have a base case in your recursive function.  Is the pressesRemaining parameter supposed to be used anywhere?  It isn't referenced or modified in your function.

Comment: The C++ code does not run.  The C# code does not run for the same reason, and contains obvious typos unrelated to your question.  The C++ code, beyond not running, also is an ill-formed program due to identifiers starting with an `_` followed by a capital letter.  On top of that, you haven't described what you tried to do to solve your problem (did you, say, use a debugger?)

Comment: sorry, I didn't copy the entire code -the important code is copied in my question. The C++ code is working as expected. The C# code - I am doing the similar vowelsAllowed - isVowel[pressedKey] one.

Comment: I don;t know how can i pass keyPadMoves similar to c++ code keyPad[ pressedKey ]

Comment: @Peti, in order for this to be a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you need to provide us with the minimal amount of code that can be used to reproduce the issue. Please read up on that article and provide a more complete example.

Comment: the actual C++ code link is included - the problem is with the first parameter in the recursive call.

Comment: Your C++ code doesn't compile - I get "The C++ Standard forbids containers of const elements because allocator<cont T> is ill-formed".

Comment: The C++ code is running using Visual Studio 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have all kinds of code in your attempted C# equivalent that don't seem to correspond to the original C++ code.
Here is a direct compilable translation, assuming that you have 'isVowel' defined somewhere:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public enum TKeyIdentity
{
    _A, _B, _C, _D, _E, _F, _G, _H, _I, _J, _K, _L, _M, _N, _O, _1, _2, _3
}

public class TraverseKeyPaths
{
    public readonly List<List<TKeyIdentity>> keyPad = new List<List<TKeyIdentity>>()
    {
        new List<TKeyIdentity> {TKeyIdentity._H, TKeyIdentity._L},
        new List<TKeyIdentity> {TKeyIdentity._I, TKeyIdentity._K, TKeyIdentity._M},
        new List<TKeyIdentity> {TKeyIdentity._F, TKeyIdentity._J, TKeyIdentity._L, TKeyIdentity._N},
        new List<TKeyIdentity> {TKeyIdentity._G, TKeyIdentity._M, TKeyIdentity._O},
        new List<TKeyIdentity> {TKeyIdentity._H, TKeyIdentity._N}
    };

    public readonly List<TKeyIdentity> keyPadRoot = new List<TKeyIdentity>() { TKeyIdentity._A, TKeyIdentity._B, TKeyIdentity._C, TKeyIdentity._D, TKeyIdentity._E, TKeyIdentity._F, TKeyIdentity._G, TKeyIdentity._H, TKeyIdentity._I, TKeyIdentity._J, TKeyIdentity._K, TKeyIdentity._L, TKeyIdentity._M, TKeyIdentity._N, TKeyIdentity._O, TKeyIdentity._1, TKeyIdentity._2, TKeyIdentity._3 };

    public TraverseKeyPaths(List<TKeyIdentity> keyPath, int pressesRemaining, int vowelsAllowed)
    {
        foreach (var pressedKey in keyPath)
        {
            int value = new TraverseKeyPaths(keyPad[(int)pressedKey], pressesRemaining, vowelsAllowed - isVowel[pressedKey]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes - you are right - I was using both c++ and C# - thank you very much